# Using confirmation prompt with cl_salv_table

Tags: abap, prompt, confirmation, alv

I need dynamically (at runtime) set or unset confirmation prompt for ALV GRID created by cl_salv_table->display( ).

I set breakpoint before CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY', manually assign 'X' to is_layo-CONFIRMATION_PROMPT, and ALV GRID asked confirmation before exit.
But I want get reference to the actual field CONFIRMATION_PROMPT to change its value at run time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <CP> TYPE C.
ASSIGN ('(SAPLSLVC_FULLSCREEN)GT_GRID-S_LAYOUT-CONFIRMATION_PROMPT') TO <CP>.
<CP> = 'X'.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).